# IsPostBack is always true when loading the ascx inside aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In my aspx page by click of a button I'm loading an ascx my problem is: 
once I click on the button I'm executing the code that load's the ascx, when the ascx is getting to Page_Load event IsPostBack() is always True.

How can I fix it?

1).Once the button is been clicked that is the code I'm using:

```
  userControls.Controls.Clear()
        lblParkingViolation.Text = "New Violation"
        userControls.Controls.Add((Page.LoadControl(Page.ResolveUrl("~/Controls/ParkingViolation/pViolationNew.ascx"))))
```

2). After the code above is been fired I'm automatically getting to the Page_Load event of the ascx:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()

        If IsPostBack() Then
            GenerateControls()
            GenerateDataSets()
        End If

        'Dim id As String = Page.Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET")
        ''id of the control that cause postback.

        ''myusercontrol1 is the id of your user control
        '' dont do any thing here post back caused by user control
        'If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) AndAlso id.Contains("myusercontrol1") Then
        '    'Do your thing

    End Sub
```

The code in comment is not working for me because it's always empty.

Comment: That's because it *is* a postback. There's nothing wrong the framework. the trouble is that you don't understand what a postback is.

Comment: I understand what post back means that not the issue.

Comment: Postback is true because it is a postback.

Comment: The thing is if I'm trying to do postback from another control on the ascx it doesn't fire.

Comment: @HuyZukerman then you need to post that code and show us what you're doing, because it probably should be.

Comment: the button is on page or inside control?